# How can you reallocate memory (e.g. add a row) to a GSL matrix?

Tags: c, memory-management, gsl

If I have a GSL matrix that has already had its memory allocated is there a simple way to reallocate that memory to, e.g., add another row?

The two ways I can think of to do it are:

```
size_t n = 2;
gsl_matrix invV = gsl_matrix_alloc(n, n);
// do something with matrix
...
// try and add another row (of length n) by reallocating data in the structure
invV->data = realloc(invV->data, sizeof(double)*(n*n + n));
invV->size1++;
```

or (using matrix views):

```
size_t n = 2;
double *invV = malloc(sizeof(double)*n*n)
gsl_matrix_view invVview = gsl_matrix_view_array(invV, n, n);
// do something with &invVview.matrix
...
// try adding another row or length n
invV = realloc(invV, invV->data, sizeof(double)*(n*n + n));
invView = gsl_matrix_view_array(invV, n+1, n);
```

I don't know if there are issue with the first method due to not changing the `tda` and `block` values in the `gsl_matrix` [structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrices.html#Matrices). Does anyone know if this would be a problem?

The second method works fine, but it's a pain having to switch back and forth between the `double` array and the matrix view.

Other suggestions are welcomed.

*Update*:

I have a simple test code using a version of my first option (called, e.g., `testgsl.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

gsl_matrix *matrix_add_row( gsl_matrix *m);

gsl_matrix *matrix_add_row( gsl_matrix *m ){
  if ( !m ){
    fprintf(stderr, "gsl_matrix must have already been initialised before adding new rows" );
    return NULL;
  }  

  size_t n = m->tda; /* current number of columns in matrix */

  /* reallocate the memory of the block */
  m->block->data = (double *)realloc(m->block->data, sizeof(double)*(m->block->size + n));
  if( !m->block->data ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not reallocate memory for gsl_matrix!");
    exit(1);
  }
  m->block->size += n;      /* update block size (number of elements) */
  m->size1++;               /* update number of rows */
  m->data = m->block->data; /* point data to block->data */
  return m;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv){
  size_t nrows = 4;
  size_t ncols = 1000;
  gsl_matrix *invV = gsl_matrix_alloc(nrows, ncols);

  //gsl_matrix *testmatrix = gsl_matrix_alloc(1000, 4000);

  /* set to zeros */
  gsl_matrix_set_zero( invV );

  /* try adding a row */
  invV = matrix_add_row( invV );

  fprintf(stderr, "nrows = %zu, ncols = %zu\n", invV->size1, invV->size2);

  /* set some values */
  gsl_matrix_set_zero( invV );
  gsl_matrix_set( invV, 4, 0, 2.3 );
  gsl_matrix_set( invV, 4, 1, 1.2 );

  gsl_matrix_free( invV );
  //gsl_matrix_free( testmatrix );

  return 0;
}
```

This seems to work fine (although I think there are some underlying memory allocation issues that might arise).

Comment: Looking at the source code for [`gsl_matrix_alloc`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gsl.git/tree/matrix/init_source.c) I think I could probably change my first method to reallocating the `block` item in the `gsl_matrix` (and updating the `tda` value). As the `data` item is just a pointer to the `block` this then should work. It would be nice to have a `gsl_matrix_realloc` (sparse matrices, `gsl_spmatrix`, do have [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sparse-matrix-allocation.html#Sparse-matrix-allocation)) or `gsl_matrix_add_row` though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Brian Gough](http://www.briangough.com/), one of the authors of the `gsl_matrix` code, seems to [suggest](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gsl/2004-09/msg00029.html) that my second option - reallocing arrays and just using vector/matrix views when necessary if the way to go.

Comment: What a daft idea to exclude realloc(). When you're doing a calculation it's more imperative to copy the data from the field rather than rely on a pointer. However some fields will need to be preserved beyond the scope of the immediate method and as such it's very inconvenient recreating the field every time from scratch.